# How to trigger Cmd from view in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm new to Elm and I ran into this problem...

We get translations for our page using something like:

```
case (translate translation.id) of
     Success: -> translation
     Failure: -> translation.id
```

Where translate just finds translation.id in a dictionary and it may or may not be there.
There are no runtime errors because you get a string either way, but we would like to log the missing translation to a rest service logger. But Elm hates side effects in the view that doesn't stem from html events so I'm not sure how to handle this.

Obviously in regular JS you could just crowbar in a fetch inside the failure case block and then return a string afterwards but that doesn't seem to be possible in Elm?

Comment: Regarding "doesn't stem from html events"; how/when do you set `translation.id` in your program?

Comment: @simplystuart They are added manually in the view, something like:


Text Translate "myWord.Id.LanguageCode"

then you get a translated string showing up for the user or "myWord.Id.LanguageCode" if it wasn't found in the dictionary

Comment: Got it. Would using a [custom element](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html) work w/ the translated string as an attribute for the custom element? That way you could dispatch an event if the translated string is empty

Comment: @simplystuart maybe I'm dense but I'm not sure how that would work :(

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the effects part of your code into the `update` function. In this case I suggest doing it when the translation arrives. There you will want something like

```
    OnTranslation translation ->
        ( { model | translation = translation } -- attach to model
        , case translate translation.id of
            Ok _ ->
                Cmd.none

            Err err ->
                -- register with the error logger
                logMissingTranslation translation.id
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

[@Odin Thorsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4969063/odin-thorsen), use `Html.node` and `Html.Attributes.attribute` to reference a [custom element](https://guide.elm-lang.org/interop/custom_elements.html) in Elm:

```
-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html.Html ()
view model =
    Html.div []
        [ translation model "key"
        , translation model "junk key"
        ]


translation : Model -> String -> Html.Html ()
translation { translations } id =
    Html.node "translated-text"
        [ Html.Attributes.attribute "translation-id" id
        , Html.Attributes.attribute "translation-text" <| translate translations id
        ]
        []


translate : Dict.Dict String String -> String -> String
translate translations id =
    case Dict.get id translations of
        Just value ->
            value

        Nothing ->
            ""
```

And in Javascript, use [`customElements.define`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) to create the custom element:

```js
    customElements.define("translated-text", class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() { super(); }
      connectedCallback() { }
      attributeChangedCallback() { this.setTextAndLogFailure(); }
      static get observedAttributes() { return ["translation-id", "translation-text"]; }
      
      setTextAndLogFailure() {
        var id = this.getAttribute("translation-id");
        var text = this.getAttribute("translation-text");
        if (text === null) return;
        this.textContent = text;
        if (!text.length) alert("Unkown translation id: " + id);
      }
    });
```

You'd replace `alert("Unkown translation id: " + id);` with the logging `fetch`.

---

Here is [an Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/htvFM3kCQy6a1) with a full solution.

Comment: I don't doubt that this works, but this is not idiomatic Elm - effects should be handled in the `update` function

Comment: @SimonH, agreed that this is not idiomatic Elm, but he is saying the translations "are added manually in the view", so there is no `OnTranslation` action if I'm understanding correctly